# .Runcommand Type Mismatch

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm getting a Type mismatched error from `AccessApp.Docmd.RunCommand "RunUpdate"`

I am trying to open a access database thru automation and run one of the public subs in a modual. This is what im using.

```
Sub VCSUpdate()
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

Dim AccessApp As New Access.Application
Set AccessApp = New Access.Application
AccessApp.AutomationSecurity = msoAutomationSecurityLow
AccessApp.OpenCurrentDatabase CurrentProject.Path & "\VICI Desktop Installer.accde"
AccessApp.RunCommand "RunInstall" '<------ errors here
AccessApp.CloseCurrentDatabase
AccessApp.Quit

Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
    Err.Raise Err.Number, Err.Source, Err.Description, Err.HelpFile, Err.HelpContext
End Sub
```

This is what the `.Runcommand` is tring to run

```
Public Sub RunInstall()
    Call LinkFrontEnd
    Call InstallDesktopVICI
End Sub
```

I tried both `AccessApp.docm.runcommand` and `AccessApp.Runcommand` both have the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've mistaken `Application.RunCommand` for `Application.Run`. Use `Application.Run` when calling a user-defined function from a string.

Comment: I now get an error "Microsoft access cannot find the procedure 'RunInstall.'

Comment: Then the question is: why can't it find the procedure? Where have you put the sub in your database? (meaning, the database open in `AccessApp`)

Comment: It is inside a module called "Module1"

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Access-VBA/articles/application-run-method-access for the documentation, don't think so (no parentheses in the example), but could be wrong

Comment: Tried `.run("RunInstall")`, `.run("RunInstall()")`, `.run RunInstall`, `.run RunInstall()` none of those work.

Comment: Should just be `.run "RunInstall"` afaik, try adding a hello world function to your `.accde` (or use a different database), and running that. Tried to replicate your error, couldn't, my best guess is it actually errors on the `RunInstall` function somewhere

Comment: That it is. Works here.

Comment: Got it working was and error with how I updated the de file